# Reduction Algorithm - Recast Any SGI Problem as Subset Sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, np-complete

Is it possible to cast any subgraph isomorphism problem as a subset sum problem so that it is possible to use dynamic programming techniques available for solving the subset sum problem to solve the SGI problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *could* do it, but every reduction known would produce a subset-sum problem with exponentially large numbers.

(Also, btilly, your homework detector is broken.)

Comment: HOW? I really don't care that the numbers will be exponentially large - I am trying to solve it as an academic exercise?

Comment: @user562688 For example, you could reduce SGI to SATISFIABILITY, then to 3-SAT, then to exactly 1-in-3 SAT, then to subset sum. I'd characterize each step as a graduate student exercise.

Comment: @user562688 For example, you could reduce SGI to SATISFIABILITY, then to 3-SAT, then to exactly 1-in-3 SAT, then to subset sum. I'd characterize each step as a graduate student exercise. – sadfg May 2 at 20:24

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this could be done.  There's no immediately clear mapping between the weights of the subset-sum problem and the structure of the graph.  The only relation between the two problems would be the subset of the graph and the subset of the set in the subset-sum problem.  The pseudo-polytime (dynamic programming) algorithm for subset-sum operates over a set of digits and a bounded sum - I seriously doubt there's any way to encode the structure of the graph in this format.  But, given that this is a homework problem, I might be wrong :)

Comment: Good question...? or just insightful?